# Find second-latest file when names can contain spaces

Tags: shell, unix

Below is my shell script.
I need to fetch second latest file size.
But when I am trying to run below script i am getting issue where ever space is there, it's trying to open it as a directory/file and giving error like no such file or directory.

Please see the below error.

```
tokenFileSubstring="/tmp/Anusha/exception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities with Pending_Fees_*.xls"
newFile=$(echo $tokenFileSubstring | sed "s/ /\\\ /g")
echo "newfile :: $newFile"
previousFileSize=`ls -lrt $newFile |tail -2 | head -1|awk '{print $5}'`
echo "previous file siz: $previousFileSize"
```

> bash-4.1$ ./basic.sh
>
> newfile :: /tmp/Anusha/exception_reports/AHJ800_Active_Facilities\ with\ Pending_Fees_2019-12-19-22-45-18.xls
> ls: cannot access /tmp/Anusha/exception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities: No such file or directory
> ls: cannot access with: No such file or directory
> : No such file or directoryees_2019-12-19-22-45-18.xls

Please help me to find second latest file size

Comment: Does the space bring any value in the names ? Can't you get rid of them before ? Spaces are always problems, you should avoid them as much as possible...

Comment: This is the logs i am getting when i run above script.spaces are not giving any values where as till space ,its opening as a directory.
newfile :: /tmp/Anusha/exception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities\ with\ Pending_Fees_*.xls
ls: cannot access /tmp/Anusha/exception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities\: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access with\: No such file or directory
: No such file or directoryees_*.xls
previous file siz:

Comment: @shellter no it's not just that, because @anusha relies on the shell expansion with the `*xls`. Doing as you says prevent shell expansion, and so the list of matching files

Comment: A backslash *inside your variable's value* is literal data, whereas a backslash *inside your code* is escaping syntax (telling the shell to parse the space that follows it as literal data rather than syntax). So using `sed` to change your variables' values will never work to modify how they're parsed, unless you're doing something awful that restarts the parsing process from the very beginning (and really, don't do that).

Comment: Anyhow, wrt. the question itself -- do you have GNU tools? If you have GNU `find` and `sort`, this becomes very, very easy.

Comment: @Zelnes, ...btw, the problem with blaming whoever *created* the filename with spaces is that sometimes filenames aren't controlled -- they can be uploaded content you're supposed to be processed; one major data-loss event at a former employer happened when a buffer overflow (in a C library used by a Python script) spilled into memory used for a filename, creating one with a space-surrounded `*` in it (and then a script that was supposed to delete stale, successfully-backed-up data didn't quote its expansions correctly, and deleted *everything* when trying to remove that one file).

Comment: ...write your code to handle all possible filenames, and that class of bug goes away; blame the people who create the filenames, and your code remains vulnerable. That kind of bug may be a low-probability event -- cumulatively, the team maintaining the tools it happened in probably had the better part of a century of experience, and it was the first time someone had seen that large an impact in practice -- but when it happens, it can be very, very expensive; better to get the details right habitually.

Comment: (...and command injection vulnerabilities, where an attacker is *intentionally* building hostile filenames to upload or hostile parameter values to submit through an admin UI, are much less uncommon; so again, better to always use practices that avoid trusting your data to be "correct", even when you don't think it'll matter)

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU tools, and your shell is bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || { echo "This script requires bash" >&2; exit 1; }

dir=/tmp/Anusha/exception_reports
pattern='ALIQD022_Active_Facilities with Pending_Fees_*.xls'

{
  read -d '' _;  # ignore very latest file entirely
  IFS= read -r -d ' ' time
  IFS= read -r -d ' ' size
  IFS= read -r -d ''  name
} < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$pattern" -printf '%T@ %s %P\0' | sort -zrg)

# note that this %()T timestamp formatting operator requires a quite new bash release.
printf 'Second latest file has name %q, size %d, time %(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T\n' \
       "$name" "$size" "${time%%.*}"
```

---

This works as follows:

- `find -printf '%T@ %s %P\0'` emits, for each file, the following:

  - A timestamp in seconds-since-the-epoch (which is to say, since 1970), followed by a space
  - The size of that file (the thing you're trying to find), followed by a space
  - The name of the file, followed by a NUL character.

  This format is important, because the timestamp and size can't contain spaces (so spaces are safe to separate them with) -- but a *name* can contain a space -- moreover, a name can even contain a newline literal! Thus, the *only* character it's safe to use to find the end of a filename is a NUL, the one character that can't possibly exist in a UNIX path.
- `sort -zrg` does a *numeric* sort (treating the timestamp as a number -- `-g` supports floating-point, whereas `-n` only considers integer components), on records that are separated by NULs (that's what the `-z` specifies). `-r` puts it in reverse order, so the most recent file is first, and the second-most-recent file (which you're trying to find) is second.
- `<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), which expands to a filename with the output of `...` -- in this case, the output of the `find | sort` pipeline. Redirecting from that process substitution with another `<` preceding it means that the content in the code block (the `read`s) are seeing the output from the process substitution, *without* [unwanted restrictions on variable scope created by using a pipeline](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- `read -d '' _` reads up to the next NUL, putting the results into the dummy variable `_` (implying to readers that we don't intend to read or use those results). Doing that as the first item processing the stream thus ignores the latest file.
- `IFS= read -r -d ' ' time` reads everything up to the next space into the variable `time`.
- `IFS= read -r -d ' ' size` reads everything up to the space after that into the variable `size`.
- `IFS= read -r -d '' name` reads everything up to the next NUL into the variable `name`.

...and thus we're able to collect the name, size and timestamp of the latest file into separate variables without [relying on the wildly-unreliable `ls` tool](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: That would truncate leading and trailing spaces in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/360486) we can build another approach. If you consider that the files you need always end up with `.xls`, we can store the beginning of the files name in `tokenFileSubstring`, and use the expansion only at the `ls` time.

```sh
tokenFileSubstring="/tmp/Anusha/exception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities with Pending_Fees_"
previousFileSize=$(ls -lrt "$tokenFileSubstring"*.xls |tail -2 | head -1|awk '{print $5}')
echo "previous file siz: $previousFileSize"
```

Also, I don't get what you're trying to retrieve whit the `ls | tail | head | awk`. Maybe you could reach the same result with only `ls | awk`

### Edit

You could also with the following command with only `ls | awk`, to simplify:

```sh
previousFileSize=$(ls -lrt "$tokenFileSubstring"*.xls | awk 'BEGIN { n = 1 } { a[n++] = $5 } END { print a[n - 2] }'
```

Comment: ls -lrt "$tokenFileSubstring"*.xls |tail -2 --This will give first 2 latest files in descending order
head -1 --in that two files first one we will get 
awk '{print $5}'---it will print 5 th column that is size

Comment: now i am getting issue like below 
newfile :: /tmp/Anusha/exception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities\ with\ Pending_Fees_*.xls
: No such file or directoryha/exception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities\ with\ Pending_Fees_*.xls
previous file siz:

Comment: @anusha Did you remove the line `echo | sed` ? It seems like not. Please, use only the code I posted

Comment: Insofar as this is depending on `ls`, it's still not particularly good practice. See [Why you shouldn't rely on `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for an analysis of which parts of `ls` output are and are not reliable across platforms, and [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for discussion of best practices around sorting or comparing files based on their metadata.

Comment: @Zelnes We should not remove spaces in file names.
I tried removing sed ,still did not work.

Comment: I tried 
previousFileSize=`ls -lrt "$tokenFileSubstring"*.xls | awk 'BEGIN { n = 1 } { a[n++] = $5 } END { print a[n - 2] }'` but i am getting below error bash-4.1$ ./basic.sh
newfile ::
*.xls: No such file or directoryception_reports/ALIQD022_Active_Facilities with Pending_Fees_
previous file siz:

Comment: @anusha, that error implies your script is saved as a DOS/Windows text file, with CRLF newlines, whereas a valid UNIX text file has only LF newlines. (You can tell that's the problem because a CR sends the cursor to the beginning of the line when it's printed, thus overwriting whatever was already there).